# How to make a model methods show in blueprint api

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I use sails mostly to provide a solid backend restful api. My problem is that in my model I need to compute some element because there is no need for then to be stored in the database. When I write those methods using what's in the [doc](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html?q=model-methods-(aka-static-or-class-methods)): the results on bluePrint API call are not showing

so to resume, having this model:

```
module.exports = {
    autoPK: true,
    attributes: {
        host: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        url: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        start: {
            type: 'date',
        },
        end: {
            type: 'date',
        },
        getDuration: function(){ // <---- I need to get this info using bluePrint 
            var diff  = this.end - this.start;
            return diff;
        }
    }
};
```

when calling *GET /api/session*

it return :

```
{
    "host": "localhost:8081",
    "url": "http://localhost:8081/db/LogStats/session",
    "start": "2015-06-19T17:35:57.000Z",
    "end": "2015-06-19T17:36:07.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2015-06-19T17:35:57.737Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-06-19T17:36:07.840Z",
    "id": "558452fde383b73a62ee07b8"
}
```

I would like to have the json above **WITH** the extra field "**duration**"

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the answers bellow here is how to implement it :

```
module.exports = {
    autoPK: true,
    attributes: {
        host: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        url: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        start: {
            type: 'date',
        },
        end: {
            type: 'date',
        },
        getDuration: function(){
            return (new Date(this.end).getTime() - new Date(this.start).getTime()) / 1000;
        },
        toJSON: function() {
            var session = this.toObject();
            session.duration = this.getDuration();
            return session;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to override the `toJSON` function of your model to augment it. Take a look here: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#model.

In the `toJSON` function, you can then tack on any desired attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you try to compare two strings which will result with `NaN`.

So you have to convert your two dates at first to `Date Objects`.

I would do it like so:

```
getDuration: function()
        return (new Date(this.end).getTime() - new Date(this.start).getTime()) / 1000;
    }
```

Then you get the difference in seconds.
Also don`t forget to "relift" your app after changing models/controllers.

Comment: You are right the date comparaison is not done right but that was not the point here as even returning a static value didn't worked